# how to draw fading seperated frames on android activity

Tags: android, layout

i am working on an android app and would like to group some of the views on each activity within a frame or a panel.

I'm still a beginner and don't have any ideas on how to do this

I know i can set the color of the background for some views but that makes the interface so stupid and ugly because there is no fading edges rather the same intensive color fills the entire view..

I want to imitate the containers in these two pics of WhatsApp app if it's possible
Please help me with this
Thanks

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/77495527/AMMAR/Screenshot_2014-03-22-03-34-17.png

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/77495527/AMMAR/Screenshot_2014-03-22-03-34-42.png

Comment: Are you looking for the bottom shadow effect ?

Comment: @Libin if this is what is called, have you seen the two images I attached? I want something similar..This may sound experimental. Thank you.

Comment: check my answer, you have to change it to your required colors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the reason behind those containers showing shadows and look very nice is that a drawable resource (png panel image) is assigned to their background. I thought that an image resource like that would only be shown as is but realized that android makes it much easier. Thank you @Libin for drawing my attention to the ability of having drawables as styles and xml files, you helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Create item layout like below and add it to a listview ....

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/top_layout_bg">
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bottom_border_bg">
  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

set background drawable for the inner two layout.. lets call as top layout and bottom border layout.

top_layout_bg.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="@color/White"></solid>
<corners android:topRightRadius="2dp" android:topLeftRadius="2dp"></corners>
</shape>
```

bottom_border_bg

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:shape="rectangle">
  <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="2dp" android:bottomRightRadius="2dp"></corners>
  <gradient android:startColor="@color/DimGray" android:endColor="@color/DimGray"></gradient>
</shape>
```

As per your requirement , change the colors.